# When creating a function in C# returning a value with many if/if else statements I get the error "not all code paths return a value"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am making a game in Unity and need my character to face a certain angle based off of axis input values. After the rest of the calculations have been made to figure out an angle based off of a triangle, I have to add a value to the angle to make it face the desired way. For some reason I get this error "not all code paths return a value"

```
   private float createDirection(float X, float Y, float theta)
{
    if (X>0&&Y>0)
    {
        return theta;
    }
    else if (X>0&&Y<0)
    {
        float new = 270.0;
        return theta + new;
    }
    else if (X<0&&Y>0)
    {
        float new = 90;
        return theta + new;
    }
    else if (X<0&&Y<0)
    {
        float new = 180;
        return theta + new;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although you may think you've covered all of the cases you are missing some. The obvious one is `x` or `y` equaling `0`, but there's also less obvious cases like `x` or `y` equaling `NaN` which is false for any comparison. There may be more. You'll want to have a default at the bottom that covers any case you've missed.

Comment: you should never, ever use "else if".  this question is the perfect example why.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a change for all the specified conditions are false; in such scenario what will be the return value? what ever it be you have to specify them as default return to make sure that the function have some return value in all cases: So the function will be like the following:

```
private float createDirection(float X, float Y, float theta)
{
    if (X > 0 && Y > 0)
    {
        return theta;
    }
    else if (X > 0 && Y < 0)
    {
        float _new = 270.0F;
        return theta + _new;
    }
    else if (X < 0 && Y > 0)
    {
        float _new = 90;
        return theta + _new;
    }
    else if (X < 0 && Y < 0)
    {
        float _new = 180;
        return theta + _new;
    }
    return 0.0F; // default Return
}
```

And one more thing: You cannot use `new` as a variable since it is a reserved word. so i have changed them as `_new` in the code please note:

Comment: Hi un-lucky - I've noticed this a lot on your other answers. Can you please properly indent/format your code when posting an answer? Thanks

Comment: @Rob : Ok Rob i will take care; and thank you for the suggestion

Comment: @un-lucky - Why did you say you'd take care and then 4 minutes later you edit someone else's answer with the same unusual indenting?

Answer (score 0):

```
private float createDirection(float X, float Y, float theta)
    {
        float t;
        if (X > 0 && Y > 0)
        {
            t = theta;
        }
        else if (X > 0 && Y < 0)
        {
            float new = 270.0;
            t = theta + new;
        }
        else if (X < 0 && Y > 0)
        {
            float new = 90;
            t = theta + new;
        }
        else if (X < 0 && Y < 0)
        {
            float new = 180;
            t = theta + new;
        }
        return t;
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't return a value when X or Y == 0.. (which isn't obvious either because you are using `float`s)

After the last else-block you can return a default value, OR, if that is not a code path which should ever be hit, you could throw an exception, i.e:

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("X and Y must be greater or lesser than zero")
```